# How to get the current row number in an SQL Server 2000 query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How do I get the row number in an SQL query using SQL Server 2000, where the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is not supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always try to use a temp table with an identity column

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(
        [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Val VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @TableFrom TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @TableFrom (Val) SELECT 'A'
INSERT INTO @TableFrom (Val) SELECT 'B'
INSERT INTO @TableFrom (Val) SELECT 'C'
INSERT INTO @TableFrom (Val) SELECT 'D'

INSERT INTO @table (Val) SELECT * FROM @TableFrom ORDER BY Val DESC
SELECT * FROM @table
```

Some of the best paging i have seen in Sql Server 2000 uses this pattern

```
DECLARE @PageStart INT,
        @PageEnd INT

SELECT  @PageStart = 51,
        @PageEnd = 100

SELECT  <TABLE>.*
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP (@PageStart - 1)
                    <ID>
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  TOP (@PageEnd)
                                <ID>
                        FROM    TABLE
                        ORDER BY <ID> ASC
                    ) SUB
            ORDER BY SUB.<ID> DESC
        ) SUB INNER JOIN
        <TABLE> ON SUB.<ID> = <TABLE>.<ID>
ORDER BY SUB.<ID>
```

Comment: Except, this is not a temp table but a table variable, and they are not support in 200 either

Comment: Table variables are supported in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 3):

Another way to create a temp table with an identity to use:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS MyID 
INTO #Temp 
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/13daeb85-da43-4166-b188-595a4a5d5282

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Row_Number() in Sql Server 2000 - it was introduced in 2005.

In case you wanted to use Row_Number for paging, here are some ideas on how to perform efficient paging in Sql 2000:

- [Efficiently Paging Through Large Result Sets in SQL Server 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml)
- [A More Efficient Method for Paging Through Large Result Sets](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this **without using a SQL defined function** could be the following:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(1) + 1 FROM YourTable t2 WHERE t2.Id < t.Id) AS RowNumber
FROM YourTable t
```

It's a bit tricky, but seems simpler that the options that others gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Could  you elaborate how the below query will solve the problem?

SELECT ( SELECT SUM(1)

FROM specimen_source_ref

WHERE specimen_source_rcd <= reg.specimen_source_rcd

) AS 'Row Number'

,*

FROM
specimen_source_ref reg

Comment: This will give you the count of the number of items smaller or equal to the current item in the list, but will not give you the unique row_number, if there are duplcate items